# Is it possible to write uploading image config code in config file/folder?

Tags: codeigniter-2

I want to put this code in config file /folder.

```
                  $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
                  $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
                  $config['max_size']     = '1000';
                  $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                  $config['max_height']  = '768';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
              $config['upload']['upload_path'] = './upload/';
              $config['upload']['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
              $config['upload']['max_size']     = '1000';
              $config['upload']['max_width']  = '1024';
              $config['upload']['max_height']  = '768';
```

And use it somewhere You need it like this

```
$this->load->library('upload', $this->config->item('upload'));
```

Answer (score 0):

George's answer will work, but there is an official way to do it:

> Simply create a new file called the upload.php, add the $config array in that file. Then save the file in: config/upload.php and it will be used automatically. You will NOT need to use the $this->upload->initialize function if you save your preferences in a config file.

With the way mentioned above you won't need to load upload library with any config it will load them automatically.

check [Codeigniter user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) for further information.